# JavaScript, variables, alert, prompt

Tags: javascript, variables, alert, prompt

Are this javascript codes the same thing?

```js
//Code Sample 1
var first = prompt("What is the first number?");
var second = prompt("what is the second number?");
var sum = Number(first) + Number(second);
alert(sum);

//Code Sample 2
var firstNumber = prompt("Please provide the first number");
var secondNumber = prompt("Please provide the second number");
alert(Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber));
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not the same thing?

Comment: No. The prompts produce different text.

Comment: Can we get rid of the `*`'s?  I assume you're only doing that for formatting reasons.

Comment: Is the part that you want to draw attention to the idea of assigning your addition expression to the variable `sum` and then alerting `sum` as opposed to just passing the addition expression directly to `alert` as in your second sample?  I ask because asking if they are "the same thing" opens the door for nitpicking things like the variable names are different and the prompt text is different.  The code is ostensibly different, so perhaps you intended to ask if the behaviour is the same (the different prompt text is still distracting in that case).

Comment: The text inside of the prompt() function is different in each of the code samples. I tested the alert output using the built in editor, and they're the same. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: If your question is if there's a difference between using a variable as the function argument or using the expression that you assigned to the variable, there's no difference. Except that you can reuse the variable for other things. And it may be easier to read and understand.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake not to specify well!
Yes, i actually wanted to know if the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is the same. The evaluation of the expression `Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber)` can be stored in a variable before passing it to the `alert` function, but it yields the same result as evaluating it straight away before passing it on.